# Is there any case where the Bimodal will be better than Not take?

Tags: cpu-architecture, branch-prediction, speculative-execution

Considering these two methods:

- Dynamic Bimodal:

  - Where we have 4 stages, 2 stages for each (taken or not taken), and alternating every time the algorithm predicts wrong, changing from taken<->not taken after 2 consecutive wrong predictions.
- Static Not Taken:

  - Here the algorithm will always predict taken OR not taken. Swapping between the two stages after every single wrong prediction.

I tested both algorithm with the follow code in C:

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {

}
```

and analyzing the `if` conditional.

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
   if( i%2 ) {

   }
   else {
   }
}
```

In both cases they are **even** (will predict right/wrong the same quantity of times).
Is there any possible simple algorithm where the Bimodal will be **better** than not taken ?

Comment: You call it "Static Not Taken" but the description sounds like dynamic prediction with 1-bit saturating counter. Which is it? Also it's better to show the assembly (pseudo)code. The initial state of the counters also matters. When you say "I tested both algorithm", how did you do that?

Comment: Dyamic prediction always alternate when it misses a branch, the `static not taken` will always predict not taken. Not in the assembly yet, first I need to find a code where `BImodal (Dynamic 2 bits)`  will be better than `Static not Taken`.  I'm testing it on paper and calculating the porcetage% where the bimodal is better predicting the when branch and when not. I'm starting with `Extreme/Strong not Taken`

Comment: OK so by `static not taken` you actually mean static not taken, because you said in the question "always predict taken OR not taken. Swapping between the two stages after every single wrong prediction. " That part was confusing.

Comment: @HadiBrais YOu are right. SOrry about that, man !

Answer (score 2):

The Static Not Taken (SNT) predictor is almost always (much) worse than any other predictor. The main reasons for this is that it's terrible with predicting the control flow of loops because it will predict not taken at every iteration.

Let's assume that the first C loop will be compiled to something like this:

```
loop body
compute loop condition
branch to the loop body if condition met
```

So there is only one branch at the end. The SNT predictor will predict not taken 4 times, but the branch is taken 3 times. So the accuracy is 25%. On the other hand, a bimodal predictor with an initial state of 10 or 11<sup>1</sup> will achieve an accuracy of 75%. The initial states 01 and 00 will achieve accuracies of 50% and 25%, respectively. 10 or 11 are considered to be good initial states.

Let's assume that the second C loop will be compiled to something like this:

```
compute the if condition
branch to the else body if condition met
the if body
non-conditional branch to the end of the loop
the else body
compute loop condition
branch to the loop body if condition met
```

So there are two conditional branches. The SNT predictor will predict not taken 8 times, but 5 of which are mispredictions (there are 5 takens and 3 not-takens<sup>2</sup>). So the accuracy is 37%. For the bimodal predictor, let's assume that each branch uses the same counter. A bimodal predictor with initial states of 10 or 11 will achieve an accuracy of 63%. A bimodal predictor with initial states of 00 or 01 will achieve accuracies of 25% and 50%, respectively. If each branch uses a different counter with the same initial state, the calculations are similar.

---

[1] Where 00 and 01 represent not taken and 10 and 11 represent taken.

[2] T, T, NT, T, T, T, NT, NT.